# подскажите пожалуйста как сделать при дефолтном варианте селект городов данной странны что бы селект сразу открывался без переключения куда либо

Tags: javascript, html, select

```
<select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="rus">Россия</option>
  <option value="uk">Украина</option>
  <option value="bel">Беларусь</option>
  <option value="jap">Япония</option>
</select>
<select name="city" id="city"></select>

<div class="result"></div> 

<script>
const cityArr = {
  rus: ['Москва', 'Санк-Петербург', 'Новосибирск', 'Екатеринбург', 'Нижний Новгород', 'Казань', 'Челябинск'],
  uk: ['Киев', 'Харьков', 'Одесса', 'Днепр', 'Донецк', 'Запорожье', 'Львов'],
  bel: ['Минск', 'Гомель', 'Могилёв', 'Витебск', 'Гродно', 'Брест'],
  jap: ['Токио', 'Киото', 'Осака', 'Иокогама'] 
}

const countryList = document.getElementById('country');
const cityList = document.getElementById('city');

if(countryList[0]){
  cityList.style.display = 'inline-block';
} else {
  
}

function getCity(){
    cityList.style.display = 'inline-block';
    let selectedCountry = countryList.options[countryList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (cityList.options.length) {
        cityList.remove(0);
    }

    let cities = cityArr[selectedCountry];
    if (cities){
        for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            let country = new Option(cities[i], i);
            cityList.options.add(country);
        }
    };
    typeInput()
};

function typeInput() {
    let countryIndex = countryList.selectedIndex;
    let cityIndex = cityList.selectedIndex;
    
    document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = 
        `${countryList.options[countryIndex].text}, ${cityList.options[cityIndex].text}`;
};

country.addEventListener('change', getCity);
city.addEventListener('change', typeInput);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо программно вызвать метод `onchange`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

function ready() {
    city.onchange();
}
```